# What are all the ways that characters can travel to the Plane of Air?

Tags: dnd-5e, planes

This is a similar question to [What are all the ways a player can get to the Astral Plane?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/104036/what-are-all-the-ways-a-player-can-get-to-the-astral-plane), but for the Plane of Air. A lot of that question is relevant.

What are all the ways can characters can go to the Plane of Air?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. *Plane shift.*  Always a popular option, if you're a mid-level planar traveler and have access to the requisite components.
2. *Gate.*  For the party that doesn't feel like spending all day traveling.
3. Other spells or creature abilities.  Most of these will be mimicking one of the first two options, so they can be lumped together.  The most straightforward would be using *wish* to travel.
4. Planar Portals.  Hard to find, but they are around.  The Air Node in *Princes of the Apocalypse* is one such example, if you're okay with hanging out with a Prince of Elemental Evil.  Classically (i.e. in older editions), you'd find these in spots that were thematically important for the plane in question, so in the midst of a tornado or permanent thunderstorm would be "good" places to look.
5. Magical Items.  A *cubic gate* can get you there, as well as a *well of many worlds*. Other items can be created to do the trick, though anyone who could make such an item already has the ability to travel using methods 1-3.
6. Travel from the Ethereal Plane.  Ethereal Curtains in the Deep Ethereal allow you to move to the border regions of the Plane of Air, and you can use various methods to get from the border regions to the plane proper.
7. Travel from one of the other Inner Planes.  The elemental planes are all connected to each other and the Elemental Chaos, the ill-defined edge of the infinite planes.  If you know the way, you can navigate from one plane to another, though certain routes take longer than others (and are quite a bit more dangerous).
8. Travel from the Astral Plane.  As traveling through the Ethereal with the added step of starting in the Astral Plane and finding your way to the Ethereal from there via a color pool.
9. The Infinite Staircase.  A magical stairwell connecting an infinite number of landings, each with some number of doors.  Each door leads to a different plane.  Though mentioned specifically as a method of travel to the Outer Planes, there's nothing that specifically prevents a door opening on the infinite cloud-filled realms of Air.

Comment: Wow that's great, do you have any sources for some of the latter methods? Book links etc? I'd be really interested to read up on some more of these.

Comment: Just about all of this comes from the DMG, chapter 2.