# Can a Way of Shadow monk use Shadow Step to teleport to the Ethereal Plane if they can see into it?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, monk, teleportation, ethereal-plane

I am currently playing a Way of Shadow monk, and my character now has a *robe of eyes*. (I am loving the *Waterdeep: Dungeon of the Mad Mage* campaign.)

The description of the [*robe of eyes*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/robe-of-eyes) says, in part (emphasis mine):

> You can see invisible creatures and objects, as well as **see into the
> Ethereal Plane**, out to a range of 120 feet.

The description of the [Way of Shadow monk](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/monk#WayofShadow)'s [Shadow Step](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/monk#ShadowStep-253) feature says, in part (PHB, p. 80; emphasis mine):

> When you are in dim light or darkness, as a bonus action you can teleport up to 60 feet to **an unoccupied space you can see** that is also in dim light or darkness.

Does this mean that I can use Shadow Step to enter the Ethereal Plane, scout around, and then Shadow Step back in on the following round?

Comment: Also, great question! While you wait to see if someone knows for sure, we have a quick [Tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) we recommend to everyone to get a feel for the site.

Comment: I will take a look. thanks

Comment: Highly related, possible dupe (leaving that to others): [Can I Misty Step off of the ethereal plane?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/170590/52137)

Comment: @Someone_Evil: The answer might be the same, but the questions are not; this one is about a monk subclass feature, and that one is about a spell. As such, they're not duplicates.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## No, Shadow Step can't teleport you to the Ethereal Plane.

#### The Ethereal Plane is not just 60 feet away.

["Planar Travel"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-d-the-planes-of-existence#PlanarTravel) describes the boundaries between planes as being distinctly more than an orthogonal distance:

> When adventurers travel into other planes of existence, they are undertaking a legendary journey across the thresholds of existence to a mythic destination where they strive to complete their quest.

#### Power is required

The proposed interpretation of Shadow Step is clever, but out of line with the power required to traverse planar boundaries. [*Etherealness*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/etherealness), [*plane shift*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/plane-shift), [*astral projection*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/astral-projection), and [*gate*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/gate) are spells that permit planar travel. They range from 7th- to 9th-level spells.

For comparison, a caster would need to be 13th-level to have a single 7th-level spell slot. [Shadow Step](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/monk#WayofShadow) is a bonus-action subclass feature that Way of Shadow monks get at 6th level.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113352/discussion-on-answer-by-gcl-can-i-shadowstep-to-the-ethereal-plane-if-i-can-see).