# Revised ranger Primeval Awareness and the ethereal plane

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, ranger, unearthed-arcana, ethereal-plane

If a UA Revised ranger uses [Primeval Awareness (pg. 4)](https://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/UA_RevisedRanger.pdf#page=4), are they able to detect enemies in the ethereal plane?

Comment: I assume you mean the Revised Ranger from the UA that I've linked? If not, please [edit] out my wrong assumption. Also welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] to find out how things work here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Yes, if the Ranger is in the Ethereal Plane

There's nothing stopping the feature from working in the Ethereal Plane, so of course it does.

### No, if the Ranger isn’t in the Ethereal Plane

The ethereal plane is a different plane of existence from the material plane, it doesn't really make a lot of sene to talk about ‘distance’ from the Ethereal plane to the Material plane, so an enemy on the Ethereal plane isn’t "within 5 miles" of the Ranger.

See also this answer about whether or not you can *Misty Step* between the Ethereal plane and Material plane for a bit more discussion on that point:

[Can I Misty Step off of the ethereal plane?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/170590/can-i-misty-step-off-of-the-ethereal-plane)